# enable_if type has unknown size

Tags: c++, boost, template-meta-programming

I have a problem where unknown code is using meta-templates which tries to dereference types at compile-time and runtime. This means, they traverse the pointer hierarchy until they find a matcher.

Now normally this works well. But when the user passes something like:

```
typedef struct _Unknown_* Unknown;
```

then it fails, because it can't be dereferenced, even though its a valid pointer and not `void*`.

How can I detect such `unknown size structs compile time and chose a different code-path to handle them, e.g. not traverse the pointer hierarchy any further.

Ok what I am looking for is this:

```
BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT(__is_of_unknown_size__<Unknwon>::value)
```

, where `__is_of_unknown_size__` is some magic construct that evaluates to true for `Unknown` or any other construct that has no size.

Thanks

Comment: Some more code would be nice

Comment: For an incomplete object type `T`, you have `sizeof(T) == 0`.

Comment: @KerrekSB: Unfortunately, sizeof() doesnt seem to work in combination with unknown types when using enable_if as selector? Or how would I use it with enable_if?

Comment: You asked for "how to detect unknown size structs" and I told you. I assumed that you had a plan for using this information.

Comment: @KerrekSB: Well maybe I find out how. But the questions of course screams "enable_if" I guess so its not too far fetched to assume that a potential solution should work in context of meta-templates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To determine types of unknown size, you can use

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T, typename=void> struct has_size : std::false_type {};
template <typename T>
struct has_size<T, typename std::enable_if<sizeof(T)>::type> : std::true_type {};
```

[**Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/aba76c7bb1daba2c). Note that `void` and `_Unknown_` are handled equivalently in this respect; They are both types to which the `sizeof` operator shall not be applied ([expr.sizeof]/1) and produces a deduction failure.

You can also add a template for convenience

```
template <typename T>
using pointee_has_size = has_size<typename std::remove_pointer<T>::type>;
```